# Why Firebase creates a String before upload when i use "POST" method

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to upload information from Excel vba with JSON to Firebase database

The question is: why method "POST" create a alphanumeric key and place the information inside it?

If i use the "PUT" method everything it saves properly but deletes all previous data.

please see the attached files to see what i mean!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP POST ([read the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-post)) is the equivalent of a "push" in Realtime Database, which creates a random child key where the object will be placed.  HTTP PUT ([read the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-put)) is just places the data at the specified key.

Comment: Do you know how can access to the information? because i used Power Query and i need to import one by one. and with vb is the seem thing, i just get the random child...

Comment: It sounds like you should ask a different question in order to explain what you're trying to do now, and the problem you're running into.